# picture from ftp server not showing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a way/whats the best way to get an image or multiple images from a database like a domain, and loading it(appearing it on the form)?
like I tried doing this but only show letters(if someone could explain would really help).

This is the class I created called `ftputility`.

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string Path { get; set; }

public List<string> ListFiles()
{
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Path);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) == false)
                {
                    var fileName = line.Split(new[] { ' ', '\t' }).Last();

                    if (!fileName.StartsWith("."))
                        files.Add(fileName);
                }
            }
            return files;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the images were in a database, it would depend on the database, but blobs hold pictures well if you use file streaming you would potentially need to do some file handling.. but it depends a lot on size, and design. you wouldnt ftp from a database

Comment: what do you mean by file handling? like the hole idea of the program is that it will apear a calendar and a user can click on a day by choice and when it clicks on the day it would apear every photo that was taken on that day , the photos are saved in a domain that we have. what is the best way to get it? and most importantly apearing the photo on the form(maybe i didnt clarify enough sorry).

Comment: You're doing ftp - this is notthing to do with a database at this time.. If you wanted to do database which was your question, I answered that